# salesforce web to lead form nested

Tags: html, forms, salesforce, sitefinity

I'm trying to insert a Salesforce Web-to-lead form into a page on our external website's CMS (we use Telerik SiteFinity if that makes a difference) using a plain old Content Block control.  Unfortunately, when the page gets rendered, SiteFinity creates its own  tag that wraps around the Salesforce-generated code and therefore creates a nested form. That obviously doesn't work.

Has anyone come up with a solution to a problem like this? I've looked at other nested form solutions and not seen one like this. The others all seem to imply a lot more control over the code that I do not have with SiteFinity (our SF instance was developed externally and all we have to work with is the CMS side of things).

The one thing I've tried that "sort of" works but is poor coding practice is to put an empty set of form tags right before the Salesforce-generated code. But then the page doesn't use the return URL, and just lists the fields that have been queued for insertion into our Leads object in our SF org.

Here's the Web-to-lead code I'm inserting (plus the bad-practice empty form):

```
<form></form>
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!-- <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<form id="sf_lead_entry" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <input name="oid" type="hidden" value="<org id>" />
    <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="https://uat.collegeadvantage.com/529intheworkplace/thank-you" />
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
    <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
    <input name="debug" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="debugEmail" type="hidden" value="software@collegeadvantage.com" />
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="80" /><br />
    <label for="company">Company</label><input name="company" id="company" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
    <label for="title">Title</label><input name="title" id="title" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
    <label for="phone">Phone</label><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email</label><input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="20" maxlength="80" /><br />
    <label for="street">Street</label><textarea name="street"></textarea><br />
    <label for="city">City</label><input name="city" id="city" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" /><br />
    <label for="state">State/Province</label><input name="state" id="state" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" /><br />
    <label for="zip">Zip</label><input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" /><br />
    Lead Channel:<textarea name="<custom control id>" id="<custom control id>" wrap="soft" type="text"></textarea><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Query" />
</form>
```

Does anyone have any ways around this?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Okay, ignore the part about the Return URL - I fixed that (took out the debug code... duh. :) )

Comment: Why don't you create a simple .net user control (ascx) and put the code there. Then register that control as a page widget and drop it on a page.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm limited to solutions that are within the CMS side of things. I don't have access to create new controls or that would be my first move. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sitefinity already have `form` tag on all pages because it is asp.net app. And you cannot nest `form` tags.

From the html5 specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

> **4.10.3 The form element**
>
> **Content model:**
>
> Flow content, but with no `form` element descendants.

In your case there two ways.

- **Best way** is to follow @Veselin Vasilev's approach and create new asp.net control for that
- Use javascript, and use `div` instead `form` tag.This JS will create hidden form, once you click submit button.

Example of replaced div with data attributes:

`<div data-sitefinity-form="" data-action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" data-method="POST">
</div>`

JS:

```
(function() {
        var pseudoForms = document.querySelectorAll('[data-sitefinity-form]');
        for(j=0;j<pseudoForms.length;j++)
        {
           var container = pseudoForms[j];
           if (container === null)
               return;
           var inputs = container.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select");
           var allInputs = document.forms["aspnetForm"].querySelectorAll('input, textarea', 'select');
           for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
               allInputs[i].addEventListener("invalid", function(event) {
                   if (Array.indexOf(inputs, document.activeElement) >= 0 && Array.indexOf(inputs, event.target) < 0)
                       event.preventDefault();
               }, true);
           }
           var submitClick = function (sender) {
               var isValid = true;
               if (isValid) {
                    function findAncestor (el) {
                        while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.hasAttribute("data-sitefinity-form"));
                        return el;
                    }
                    var pForm = findAncestor(sender.target || sender.srcElement);
                   var form = document.createElement("form");
                   form.style.display = "none";
                   form.setAttribute("action", pForm.getAttribute("data-action"));

                   if (pForm.getAttribute("data-method"))
                        form.setAttribute("method", pForm.getAttribute("data-method"));
                   if (pForm.getAttribute("enctype"))
                       form.setAttribute("enctype", pForm.getAttribute("enctype"));
                   else
                       form.setAttribute("enctype", document.forms["aspnetForm"].getAttribute("enctype"));
                   form.setAttribute("encoding", document.forms["aspnetForm"].getAttribute("encoding"));

                   form.appendChild(pForm);

                   sender = sender.target || sender.srcElement;
                   if(sender)
                   {
                       var submitHiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
                       submitHiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                       submitHiddenInput.setAttribute("name", sender.name);                                
                       submitHiddenInput.setAttribute("value", sender.value || "Submit");
                       form.appendChild(submitHiddenInput);
                   }

                   document.body.appendChild(form);


                   form.submit();
                   return false;
               }
           };
           var handleFormSubmitElements = function (elementName) {
               var allSubmitElements = container.getElementsByTagName(elementName);
               var elementCount = allSubmitElements.length;
               while(elementCount) {
                   typeAttr = allSubmitElements[elementCount - 1].getAttribute("type");
                   if(typeAttr == "submit") {
                       var currentClick = allSubmitElements[elementCount - 1].onclick;
                       if (currentClick)
                           allSubmitElements[elementCount - 1].onclick = function () { if (currentClick()) return submitClick(); else return false; };
                       else
                           allSubmitElements[elementCount - 1].onclick = submitClick;
                   }
                   elementCount--;
               }
           };
           handleFormSubmitElements("input");
           handleFormSubmitElements("textarea");
           handleFormSubmitElements("select");
           handleFormSubmitElements("button");
        }
   })();
```

Comment: If they use Feather template, they can have multiple forms in the document, not nested, as you already said.